# Generate one js file from all signalr js files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I had taken the code below form this tutorial initially: [SignalR Getting Started Application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Getting-Started-b9d18aa9) that will create a chat room. I've cleaned the html code a little bit to get only the part that I am going to need. I verified chat is still working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        console.log('name is: ' + name);
        console.log('message is: ' + message);
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.send("khaled7", "message9");
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can there are 3 javascripts files and 1 script block:

Now, I need to join all these scripts into one single file and send that to my remote mobile clients. I'm still at the web side, so I started joining the files/script top down. Joining the top 2 worked OK, but once trying to add the 3rd (/signalr/hubs), I get a 404 error in my chrome console:

> http://localhost:52528/HubSample/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1464332439400

It is imperative for me to join them all. How can I go around this error!?

Comment: Try and update your jquery to >2 version. I use jquery-2.2.2.min.js with jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js. Works great

Comment: maybe my question wasn't too clear. I went and changed the title to make it more descriptive of my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"/signalr/hubs" is not a physical file, it's a [dynamically generated JavaScript code](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#dynamicproxy).

> SignalR creates the JavaScript code for the proxy on the fly and
>   serves it to the client in response to the "/signalr/hubs" URL.

What you want to do is to create a [physical file for the SignalR generated proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy) that you can add to your single file:

> 1. Install the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils NuGet package.
> 2. Open a command prompt and browse to the tools folder that contains the SignalR.exe file. The tools folder is at the following location:
>      `[your solution folder]\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.2.1.0\tools`
> 3. Enter the following command:
>      `signalr ghp /path:[path to the .dll that contains your Hub class]`
>      The path to your .dll is
>      typically the bin folder in your project folder.
> 4. This command creates a file named server.js in the same folder as signalr.exe.
> 5. Put the server.js file in an appropriate folder in your project, rename it as appropriate for your application, and add a reference to
>      it in place of the "signalr/hubs" reference.

**The problem is that you'll have to do this for every change in your hubs**. Every. Single. time.